# Am I stuck with only 1 position for my angular toastr for the life time of the app?

Tags: angularjs, angular-toastr

I would love to utilize angular toastr, but I've read that you can only configure the position via configuration. So I can set it once and that's it? I can't display toaster messages in any other regions on the screen other than the one I specified in the initialization of the app?

Comment: Are you using angular-material? Would you share some code?

Comment: no. And no code is necessary to show for my situation.

Comment: You can pass in configuration details on a "per toast" basis that override the global defaults for that specific instance.  e.g. `toastr.info('<input type="checkbox" checked> Success!', 'With HTML', {
  allowHtml: true
});`

Comment: @BrendanGreen I'm specifically looking for how to change the positionClass. Do you know if it's possible to change the position class on a "per toast" basis?

Comment: Did you try passing the `positionClass` into the config for the toast?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I've done it during the config. But you cannot add positionClass as an argument when creating a new toast

Comment: Time to show code.  `toastr.info('Info!', 'With HTML', { positionClass: 'whatever' });` should work.  How else would the sample / demo page allow you to select the position dynamically

Comment: @BrendanGreen that does not work. I think the creator specifically said you can't do that. I'm looking for a work around.